# scope this in Jquery pattern "Lightweight"

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, scope

I hope that you understand my english.

I try use Jquery pattern "Lighrweight" (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/)

But I have a problem for call method and the scope of this.

I bind plugin on table :

```
    $("#tableSurface0").flexTab();
    $("#tableSurface1").flexTab();
```

My Jquery plugin :

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {


    var pluginName = 'flexTab',
        defaults = {
            wrapOverflowHeight : true
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
        $("th:not([noflex])", this.element).on("mousedown", menuContextuel);
    };

    menuContextuel = function(event)
    {
        //BUG
        console.log( ?? ); // show this.element of constructor
    }

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, 
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, 
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

So I can not call this.element in menuContextuel function without add data in event handler :

```
Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
    $("th:not([noflex])", this.element).on("mousedown", { table:this.element }, menuContextuel);
};
...
menuContextuel = function(event)
{
   console.log( event.data.table );
}
```

There-he has another solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the function is being called and the "this" is the element that is clicked on. Use can use [jQuery's proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) so maintain the scope of "this" that you are after.

```
$("th:not([noflex])", this.element).on("mousedown", $.proxy(menuContextuel,this));
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know $.proxy.

A last question. If in my contextuelMenu function I want enter in my element clicked, the best method is that it ?

    $("th:not([noflex])", this.element).on("mousedown", $.proxy(menuContextuel,this));
    ...
    menuContextuel = function(event)
    {
        console.log( this.element ); //great
        console.log ( event.currentTarget ) //the clicked <th>
    }